# Passenger Disappeared from Webserver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, redhat

I have a web server running a ruby on rails application and passenger with the following specs

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4 (Tikanga)
Server version: Apache/2.2.3
Server built:   May 28 2012 08:45:26
PHP 5.3.8 (cli) (built: Oct  3 2012 18:55:28) 
rvm 1.16.19 (stable)
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 MBARI 8/0x6770 on patchlevel 358) [x86_64-linux], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2012.02
Rails 3.2.8
Phusion Passenger version 3.0.18
```

This morning I revieced an e-mail from the Server Admin saying the website has started returning errors. I log on to the server to find that passenger is not only not running, but some how got completely uninstalled from the server.

Here is the error the server threw many times

```
ruby: No such file or directory -- /directory/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/gems/passenger-3.0.18/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server (LoadError)
[ pid=3324 thr=48010014159632 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:884 time=2012-11-14     10:59:55.403 ]: Unexpected error in mod_passenger: Cannot spawn application '/var/www/html/application/current': Could not read from the spawn server: Connection reset by peer (104)
Backtrace:
 in 'virtual Passenger::SessionPtr Passenger::ApplicationPool::Client::get(const Passenger::PoolOptions&)' (Client.h:742)
 in 'Passenger::SessionPtr Hooks::getSession(const Passenger::PoolOptions&)' (Hooks.cpp:312)
 in 'int Hooks::handleRequest(request_rec*)' (Hooks.cpp:585)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by reinstalling passenger like so

```
gem install passenger
```

All my configuration was still in place, and it resumed the application as if nothing had happend.